# Format a decimal with toLocaleString to show 2 decimals and a coma

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to format a number which is a price into this format x,xxx.xx, for example 1,000.55, the number from the database is a decimal(8,2) which is 1000.55, but when I try to use toLocaleString on this number it doesn't work.

This is the function I'm using in vue

```
formatProdPrice(value) {
    return value.toLocaleString(['en-US', [{minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}]]);
}
```

And this is where I use it

```
formatProdPrice($page.price.price)
```

The expected output is 1,000.55 but the actually output right now is 1000.55. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the brackets all over the place, just do `toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})`

Comment: @georg I tried that too without any success

Comment: I think we need more context, your code works in the console.

Comment: @ry4nolson it stopped working when I changed the data type in the database from int to decimal (8,2) nothing else has changed

Comment: that's beside the point. the code that you posted works as it's posted. The issue is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: actually. your posted function results in an error, the square brackets are in the incorrect places.

Comment: Sounds like `value` is being treated as a string. Try `parseFloat(value).toLocaleString...`

Comment: @Nancy This is most likely coz the value param must be string. try this out `parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})`

Comment: @ambianBeing thanks! This was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can also format it as currency using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

```
function formatProdPrice(value) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" }).format(value);
}

formatProdPrice(1000.55); // returns "$1,000.55"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the function signature ("Syntax" section) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

These square brackets around arguments mean that arguments are optional, it's not an array literal. So, you should ommit them in your code.

Also, I recommend to check if the "value" is a number before.

```
function formatProdPrice(value) {
    return Number(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change :

```
formatProdPrice(value) {
    return value.toLocaleString();
}
```